# Python-Polars merge lists of lists

Tags: python, list, python-polars

Hello I have a polars dataframe with a column that contains lists of lists.
like this:

```
| nodes                 │ 
-------------------------
| [[1], [1,2], []]      |
| [[2]]                 |
| [[1], [2]]            |
-------------------------
```

I want to merge all these sublists into one single list like this:

```
| nodes                 │ 
-------------------------
| [1, 1, 2]             |
| [2]                   |
| [1, 2]                |
-------------------------
```

I am pretty sure that must be doable pretty easily but I don't find the correct way in the API. Thanks for any help!

Comment: It would help if you gave the code for your example dataframe. It looks like maybe you could: `df.with_columns(pl.col("nodes").list.eval(pl.element().flatten().drop_nulls()))`

Answer (score 0):

lists implement the `__add__` dunder method which concatenates lists together (e.g. `[1] + [2] = [1,2]`). Thus you can use the `sum` function (which uses `__add__`). However you need to set a `start` value (defaults to 0 but we need the 0 equivalent for lists: `[]`

```
def f(x):
    return sum(x,[])

df["nodes"]=df["nodes"].apply(f)
```