# Polars merging list of lists into a comma separated string while removing duplicates

Tags: python, python-polars

Theres a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77053181/python-polars-merge-lists-of-lists) already on this, but the answer does not solve the question.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 1], "name": ['jenobi', 'blah', 'jenobi'], 
                "company": [[['some company 1', 'some company2'], ['some company2']], 
                [['company 1'], ['company 2', 'company 3']],
                [['some company 1'], ['some company2', 'some company 1', 'some company 2']]]
               })
```

Dataframe follows the schema as above. Want to merge the lists of lists during a groupby and aggregate on the id and name.

Want the result to show a string concatenated value, for example jenobi should show the following company: "some company 1, some company2, some company 2".

Have tried doing a groupby agg on the company and flattening the result however this produces a panic error.

Based on jqurious comments, the issue with doing a flatten then a join is that the list is flattened. However, there are double quotes around the flattened sub-lists in the output.

[image]

This is produced from the following..

```py
df.groupby("name").agg(pl.col("company").flatten().list.join(", "))
df.with_columns(pl.col("company").list.unique())
```

Ideally, the final result will show..
[image]

##### Panic Error

```py
data = (
    pl.read_parquet(r"input.parquet")
    .select("id", "name", "company")
    .groupby("id", "name")
    .agg(
        pl.col("company").flatten().list.unique()
    )
)
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the code that generates a PanicError? It may need to be reported as a bug. It would also help if you can show the actual final Dataframe you expect. It sounds like `df.group_by("id", "name").agg(pl.col("company").flatten().list.join(", "))` but it's difficult to tell from the description alone.

Comment: @jqurious - edited the OP based on your comments including screenshot of the panic, with the code produced. The input.parquet file is 3Gi of shape (31803425, 6).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yeah, it's a little awkward as it's a list of lists but then `.agg()` creates another level of nesting. You could remove the nesting first `df.explode("company").explode("company").group_by("name").agg(pl.col("company").unique())` - but perhaps there is a neater approach. **Edit:** Maybe `df.group_by("name").agg(pl.col("company").flatten().flatten().unique())`

Comment: what version are you using? in 0.18.4 a group by is df.groupby

Comment: I'm on the latest version: `0.19.12` - The underscore was introduced in [`0.19.0`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.19.0) (you'll get a deprecation warning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From version `0.19.9` we can expand/enlarge the repr for list columns.

```py
pl.Config(fmt_table_cell_list_len=-1, fmt_str_lengths=120)
```

You can `.flatten()` each level of nesting inside the `.agg()` and then call `.unique()`

```py
(df.group_by("name")
   .agg(pl.col("company").flatten().flatten().unique())
)
```

```py
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ name   ┆ company                                               │
│ ---    ┆ ---                                                   │
│ str    ┆ list[str]                                             │
╞════════╪═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ blah   ┆ ["company 1", "company 2", "company 3"]               │
│ jenobi ┆ ["some company2", "some company 2", "some company 1"] │
└────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

- **Note:** `df.groupby` was renamed to `df.group_by` in `0.19.0`